# C# - OpenOfficeXML Date Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, epplus

I am having an issue when passing some data to an Excel spreadsheet, using OOX. Thing is, everything works great, except the dates, which are shown in a numeric value instead of the datetime format. Here's my code:

```
private object ProcessXLSFile(PayeesWorkingHoursFullDataDTO payeesWorkingHoursFullDataDTO)
    {
        DataTable dt = Functions.ObjectToDataTable(payeesWorkingHoursFullDataDTO.ListWorkingHours);

        ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();

        //Create the worksheet
        ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("WorkSheet1");

        //Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. Print the column names on row 1
        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);

        string _range = "G2:G" + (dt.Rows.Count + 1).ToString();
        using (ExcelRange col = ws.Cells[_range])
        {
            col.Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0.00";
            col.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Right;
        }

        _range = "J2:J" + (dt.Rows.Count + 1).ToString();
        using (ExcelRange col = ws.Cells[_range])
        {
            col.Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
            col.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
        }

        _range = "T2:T" + (dt.Rows.Count + 1).ToString();
        using (ExcelRange col = ws.Cells[_range])
        {
            col.Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd-MM-yyyy";
            col.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
        }

        //Write it back to the client
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Payee-Grid.xlsx");
        Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
        Response.End();

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

These lines are the ones where the columns should be converted to datetime:

```
_range = "J2:J" + (dt.Rows.Count + 1).ToString();
        using (ExcelRange col = ws.Cells[_range])
        {
            col.Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
            col.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
        }
```

But that's definitely not working.

This is the code where I create the DataTable:

```
public static DataTable ObjectToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }
```

Debugging the columns I have been able to see that, up to the lines where I format the columns to "dd-MM-yyyy", the date information is still in datetime format. I have tried everything, but I really don't seem to be able to get this to work properly. Do you guys have any idea on how to make it work?

Comment: Hi,  there is a link I think which may help you http://polymathprogrammer.com/2009/11/09/how-to-create-stylesheet-in-excel-open-xml/

Comment: Why are you converting to a DataTable? EPPlus can handle `List<T>` with `LoadFromCollection`

Comment: @VDWWD honestly, I'm working on top of an inherited solution, just solving bugs. I didn't really implemented this code originally, so as to why the previous developer chose to use OOX and DataTable in particular is unknown to me.

Comment: What is the class definition for `ListWorkingHours`?

Comment: Did you try escaping the / as in my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the width of the columns. For some reason, if the width was too narrow, all text in the cells was converted to ####, weird thing. I figured it out because it was only a visual glitch, the values in the cells where the right ones. Using AutoFit() in all the cells of the grid solved the problem. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
_range = "J2:J" + (dt.Rows.Count + 1).ToString();
        using (ExcelRange col = ws.Cells[_range])
        {
            col.Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd\\/MM\\/yyyy";
            col.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
        }
```

Sometimes, for reasons unknown, you have to escape things :-)

Comment: Hi Mario, thanks for your answer. I did try that but it didn't work; the values in the cells where the correct ones, though; hence, the problem was only in the way the data was being displayed. Resizing the columns fixed the issue. Thanks!